# Connected to Server but not receiving data after emit Swift iOS

Tags: ios, socket.io, swift5

I am using https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift library. I am able to connect to server after sending params "room" i am not able to get response from server after emit. I have to listen on **verified** key for getting response I tried many solutions
Below My Code:-

```
import Foundation
import SocketIO

class MySocket: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = MySocket()
var socketIOClient: SocketIOClient!

let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://xyz.5001")! as URL, config: [
    .connectParams(["room": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "roomID") ?? ""]),
    .log(true),
    .selfSigned(true),
    .forceWebsockets(true),
    .reconnects(true),
    .forceNew(true)
])

func connected() {
    print("socket try to connecting.....")

    let socket = manager.defaultSocket
    socket.emit("join",["room": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "roomID") ?? ""])
    
    // Socket Events
    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) { (data, _) in
        print("socket connected")
//            socket.emit("join", ["room": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "roomID") ?? ""])

    }
    
    socket.on(clientEvent: .error) { (data, _) in
        print("socket error")
    }
    
    socket.on("verified") { (data, _) in
        if let json = data[0] as? [String:AnyObject] {
           print(json)
        }
    }
    
    socket.connect()
   }
 }
```

Usage :-

```
 MySocket.sharedInstance.connected()
```

Could Some one help me

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to server and emitting, back-end has problem